# Bad Request 400 in Typescript

Tags: typescript, post

I'm working in Typescript using POST API. I had checked URL in postman it is working fine. My Code looks like this:

```
const url= `https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=7.0`;
const headers={
    Authorization: `Basic auth (I'm using PAT Token),
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8;",
  };
  const Obj={
    "op":"add", 
    "path":"/fields/System.Title", 
    "from": null, 
    "value": "Sample task"
  };
  try{
  const response=await fetch(url, {
    method: `POST`,
    body: JSON.stringify(Obj),
    headers: headers
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error! status: ${response.status}`);
  }
  const result = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
 }
catch (error) {
    console.log('error message: ', error.message);
    return error.message;
}
```

Whenever I add new title in UI and pressing add button I'm getting 400 error. I'm not sure whether I missed anything. Please let me know if you had found the answer.

My expectation is to add the title in UI using POST API.

Comment: 400 probably has nothing to do with typescript. Something is probably wrong with your payload. check the error from the API. also your code snippet is one big string

Comment: The error shows 400 other than that there are no errors. I had checked the payload also it is correct. Here, the content type is application/json-patch+json is only supported in postman